# Eloquent Laravel foreign key to spivot table

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, foreign-keys, laravel-5.3

I want to make a foreign key relation to a spivot table in Laravel.

Thats what the schema looks like:
[image]

I need to make a relation from the 'roles' table to the spivot table 'organisations_users'.

I want to do this with the column 'role_id' in the 'organisations_users' table.

Now my question is: How do I make this relationship in my models in Laravel. I'm using Laravel Eloquent.

I've already made 2 models 'User' and 'Organisation'.
This is the code:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = [];

public function organisations(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Organisation', 'organisations_users')->withPivot('date_start','date_stop','role_id');
}
}
```

This is the 'User' model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Organisation extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'organisations_users')->withPivot('date_start','date_stop','role_id');
    }
}
```

This is the 'Organisation' model.

Comment: Do try and keep your questions more minimal. Remove comments that don't matter. Trim down code that's not relevant. If you must include a schema, try and put it in as compact a form as possible.